# Registered voters by county

Tags: usa, elections

i am looking information about presidential election 2016 by county. There is information how many people voted for Clinton and Trump ( https://data.world/aaronhoffman/us-general-election-2016 ) However I cannot find data how many people are registered for vote by county. Do you know where i can find such data?

Comment: probably open elections and/or the data for democracy slack channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of our data scientists pointed out that, while not a Census thing, you should check out:

https://data.world/data4democracy/election-transparency/

Or specifically:

https://data.world/data4democracy/election-transparency/workspace/file?filename=PartyRegistration.csv

This might be helpful if you prefer to stay on data.world.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If you google `us voter registration per "county"` (quoting as shown), you will get links to many states' voter registration data.

A painful way to do this is to visit each state government site (www.state.xx.us, where xx is the state's two letter postal code; you will normally be redirected), and then search on their website.

For example, www.state.ia.us redirects to iowa.gov. When you search for "voter registration by county" (no quotes), you get to https://sos.iowa.gov/elections/voterreg/regstat.html which has the info you want.

An even more aggressive approach would be to email the governments and ask for this information.

Table 4a on census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/voting-and-registrat‌​ion/… yields state data; county data is conspicuously missing, but poke around.

County data may not be available for free, at least not from the Census. If you search data.gov for voter registration or county voter registration (no quotes), you'll get some useful hits, but nothing really super useful.